# HDDs don't boot via SATA, but boot via USB

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, ssd, sata

Can't boot any HDD via SATA cables in the mobo, but can boot via USB.

- I have tested now three hard drives at this point, all of them do not
  boot on SATA, but all of them boots via SATA switcher to USB.
- All of them make different sounds. Sounds like all of them are trying to boot but failing.
- Apps like DiskCheckup and CrystalDiskInfo report that all drives are healthy.
- I ran the `chkdsk /b /f /v /scan` command on each drive and found no bad sectors or any issue reported.
- I used multiple SATA cables and ports, same issue. But the SSDs boot fine on very same cables and ports.

Specifications:

```
PSU Supremo FM2 Gold 650W
Prime B450-Plus
```

**Update 1**
Decided to unplug BDROM and test the HDDs with the very first SATA power plug that goes right to the PSU and it worked, all HDDs boots from the first SATA power cable, but fails from the rest, except SSDs.

A graphic demonstration of current situation:
[image]

It's like it's not sending enough power to the rest of SATA plugs? But enough power for SSDs?

I ordered some SATA splitters to test it with the first working plug and see if I can connect all HDDs through that and use the rest just for SSDs. Will update later this week.

**Update 2 / Solved**
I did what @AndrewMorton adviced, I had no idea I still had backup SATA power cables in the original box from few years ago laying around. Now I have 2 cables for SATA going into PSU, one for SSDs and one for HDDs, and it all works!

Comment: Have you tried re-plugging the PSU end of the SATA power cable to make sure it has a good connection there?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi, but why it doesn't interrupt SSDs?

Comment: SSDs usually use only the +5 V rail, but HDDs also use the +12 V rail.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So, interesting find. While replugging all the modular cables to different slots didn't give any results at the same time I decided to unplug BDROM and test on that one and weirdly all HDDs boot. It's the very first one SATA cable plug that goes directly from PSU, and the other three that are extended after this one fail HDDs, but not the SSDs. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that just the 12 V wire has broken after the first connector. Unlikely, but possible. Did the PSU come with some more SATA power cables you can try with?

Comment: @AndrewMorton that was it, I had a backup laying around in the original box. Can you please post this as a summarized answer so I can choose it as correct answer and close the thread. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've made an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSDs use just the 5 V rail for their power, whereas HDDs also use the 12 V rail (for the motor). So, if there is a break in the 12 V line in the power cable, SSDs will still work but HDDs will not.

You can try a different power cable for the HDDs: most PSUs come with at least two for the drive power.

N.B. You might want to add a label to the faulty power cable for future reference.